# Does a well pump require more force to pump if placed at the middle of a 20 ft well instead of top?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Let's say we have a typical well hand pump with a nosle & lever at the top. For example this well is 20 ft deep.
The question is: does the lever require more force to pump if the pump was placed in the middle of the well? (at 10 ft)
It seems that it would considering more water weight would be weighing down onto the piston than being at the top of the pump.
Thanks![image]

Comment: "Pulling" water up 40 feet won't happen, the max is about 30 feet

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where the pump draws water from, the force/energy you will have to use is equivalent to lifting it from the water-top.

This is because the surrounding water will push water to the top level naturally through [hydrostatic pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatics#Pressure_in_fluids_at_rest).

This is assuming an ideal fluid.

In reality, if you are pumping constantly and the fluid is not ideal and has some viscosity; then the shorter pipe will be more efficient (as less energy is lost to friction).

Answer (score 0):

No matter where the pump mechanism is, in a vertical well, it will require the same force to lift the same amount of water the same distance above the surface.  Whether it is above or below the surface of the water, the column of water being lifted from the surface of the water to the outlet will weigh the same. The suction pump in your diagram is for a shallow water well, as even a complete vacuum can only lift water about 10 meters. Deeper wells do have the pump near the bottom, like most modern day electric submersible pumps, as water can be "pushed" upwards higher distances with higher pressure.

Comment: Thank you! Another Q?: So if the force equals the same either how much water is weighing down on the piston then think about this scenario?

A deep well with a 5x2x5 hand pump near the bottom that can push around 200 gallons up 5 feet per lever stroke.
But it pushes 200 gallons from this 5x2x5 pump section up into a smaller section of the well let's say into a 1x1x1 tube that's 500 feet high. 

Is the stroke force on the lever still the same regardless of the different dimensions? Pumping from a 5x2x5 section into the smaller 1x1x1 section. Which would be 200 gallons up 5 feet at a time.

Comment: @Ripley Gallegos: Friction of water traveling through longer or narrower pipes may slightly increase force needed. Pipes narrow enough to cause a restriction in water flow may increase friction.

Comment: You know iv been seeking an important question regarding this one. "I'v asked this other question several different ways now and have gotten an answer that hasnt totally made sense to me. For example if I had a 5x5x1ft plunger at the bottom of a 100ft deep well assuming (1000gallons); that in order to lift the plunger up 5 ft I must lift all above water (1000 gallons) upwards 5ft? Because I continue being told that I'm only displacing 5x5x5ft of water and that's only 187.5gallons.. Not 1000. HUGE difference!"

Comment: the water pressure at 100 feet deep is a bit more than 44 psi, this is enough to push water 100 feet up into your pipe. Now, where ever your pump is in that 100 feet of pipe, adding about 2.23 psi will lift the water another 5 feet in the pipe.

Comment: THANK YOU! I APPRECIATE THE ANSWER!